# Local area network computer to computer backup software

Tags: windows-7, mac, backup, lan

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Help to keep and update backup copy of folders](https://superuser.com/questions/256782/help-to-keep-and-update-backup-copy-of-folders)

Hi!

I would like to back up my other computers on my local home network to my computer. What software would you suggest? I liked crashplan, however their confusing UI, and its ability not to sync, turned me away.  But it has the right idea.

A bonus would be if the software did not compile everything in to one file, but its ok if it does.
Also I would like it to be free

Comment: What do you mean it couldn't sync? CrashPlan supports incremental and differential backups, even for the free version.

Answer (score 0):

I think Crashplan is really the best LAN solution but if you don't like it, you could try using [Dropbox](http://dropbox.com).  I know this isn't over your LAN, but still, it syncs all the files in the Dropbox and it's cross-platform.  It's also free if you don't need over 2 GB of space.

Comment: The 0.7.x releases of Dropbox can do LAN-based copying (in addition to uploading to their servers).

Answer (score 0):

http://www.bacula.org/en/ - I haven't use it yet, but I heard a lot of good thing about this program. It's Open Source (GPLv2). It is created for enterprise networks, but why not try it it at home?

One more useful link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Free_backup_software

Answer (score 0):

You might look at [SpiderOak](https://spideroak.com/) (2GB for free). I have not used it, but it looks like it has sync features akin to, but more flexible than, Dropbox. But [some](https://spideroak.com/faq/do_files_have_to_be_backed_up_before_they_can_be_syncd) [FAQs](https://spideroak.com/faq/how_do_i_sync_to_a_local_drive_without_having_the_contents_of_that_drive_uploaded_as_well_local_external_drive_storage) indicate that it may not do local copying like CrashPlan or (recent releases of) Dropbox.

Answer (score 0):

This is tagged Windows 7, so why not use Windows 7's [built in backup tools](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windows-7/features/backup-and-restore.aspx)? I've found that it works quite well. You can set up a network share on whichever computer you want to host the backups on, and set the other computers to backup to that drive. When the backup is available, you'll also get Windows' built in previous versions feature, where you can see previously backed up versions of a file in its properties window. Also, image backups make it a lot easier to restore after a catastrophic crash, which Windows backup does automatically as well.