# Backup solution via LAN

Tags: windows-7, backup, network-shares

I have two systems say client A and client B. Both are on a LAN. There are some folders on client A which are very important and as such I need continuous back up of those folders on client B. I have installed *Golden FTP server* on client B and want an automatic synchronization of client A with client B.

Please provide the steps to achieve the following.

Comment: Here you find [more alternatives](http://superuser.com/questions/82335/local-area-network-computer-to-computer-backup-software)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this even without third-party software, using one of the windows built-in programs "xcopy" or "robocopy" (depends on wether you want to just fill directory B with new or changed files from A or you want a mirror copy of A, including the deletion of files, no longer present in A, on the remote end B).

Just create a .bat file with the corresponding command, and add that file to sheduled tasks, so it will be executed automatically every day/week/[whatever time you want].

Here is a quick example for an xcopy command (assuming "C:\directoryA" is the source and "\remote-pc\backup\directoryB" is the backup folder) :

```
xcopy /M /S /Y "C:\directoryA" "\\remote-pc\backup\directoryB"
```

Note that the remote folder has to be accessible in this way, that means you may have to setup a network share.

Comment: Furthermore you can then schedule this batch file via Task Scheduler to be executed every x interval

Answer (score 0):

FTP is not good for backup. Uninstall the FTP server unless you need it for something else.

CrashPlan fits your case perfectly and their free version will do what you want exactly. Check this link:

http://www.crashplan.com/consumer/crashplan.html

They also have a "how does it work" video on that link you might want to check.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

use karen's replicator it's really simple and makes two directories copies of each other.

I've also used Cobian backup for more options - its very good (again quite simple)